# How to handle wizard progress bar in html5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, progress-bar, wizard

I want to achieve section progress bar animation based on moving forward and backward

consider i have four sections each section has forward and backward button,on section 1 after filling details click on next increase progress bar by 25%,now goes to section 2 after filling click on next it should increase by 50%.

on the same case from section 2 i have both move forward and backward button if i click backward from section 2 it goes to section 1 simultaneously progress bar also need to decreased by 25% for this kind of scenario is there any predefined library available or is there any better way to handle this

```
 <div class="row hidden-xs name-progress-bar" style="margin-top:-15px">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="progress" id="progress1">
                            <div class="progress-bar" data-progress1 = "0" id="myBar" role="progressbar"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="progress" id="progress2">
                            <div class="progress-bar2" data-progress2 = "0" id="myBar2" role="progressbar"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress-group col-md-12">
                        <div class="custom-name-progress-bar" [style.width.%]="constWidth" *ngFor="let configData of progressBarConfig | objectToArray">
                            <button class="progress-button">{{configData.name}}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 static activeProgressBar(){
        var total = 4;
        var current = parseInt(jQuery('.page-heading-mobile').attr('data-step'));
        var average  = (current/total)*100
        //var average = (100/totalSection);
        var active= parseInt(jQuery('.progress-bar').attr('data-progress1'));
        active = active + average;
        var activePercent = active + '%';
        var progress = jQuery('.progress-bar');
        jQuery('.progress-bar').attr('data-progress1',active);
        progress.css('width',activePercent);
    }

    static completedProgressBar(){
        var total = 4;    
        var current = parseInt(jQuery('.page-heading-mobile').attr('data-step'));
        var average  = (current/total)*100
        //var average = (100/totalSection);
        var active = parseInt(jQuery('.progress-bar2').attr('data-progress2'));
        active = active + average;
        var activePercent = active + '%';
        var progress = jQuery('.progress-bar2');
        jQuery('.progress-bar2').attr('data-progress2',active);
        progress.css('width',activePercent);
    }
```

I have two progress bar on is active and competed with two different colors
[image]

Back and continue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
//HTML    

<progress max="100" value="0" id="progressBar"></progress>
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="button-container">
      <button id="back">Back</button>
      <button id="saveContinue">Save &amp; Continue</button>
    </div>
    </div>

//Script

$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  var countOfTabs = $("#tabs li").length;
  var slotValue = 100/countOfTabs;

  $("#saveContinue").on("click", function() {
    var currentTab = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');
    currentTab++;
    $("#tabs").tabs({
          active: currentTab 
      });

       if(currentTab==0){
            currentTab = 1;
          }
      for(i=1;i<=currentTab;i++){
        if(i==currentTab){

          var finalVal = slotValue*i;
            $("#progressBar").attr("value", finalVal);
        }
      }

  });

  $("#back").on("click", function() {
  var currentTab = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');

      if(currentTab==0){
        $("#progressBar").attr("value", "0");
      }else{
        $("#tabs").tabs({
          active: currentTab - 1
        });
      }
        for(i=1;i<=currentTab;i++){
        if(i==currentTab){
         i--;
          var finalVal = slotValue*i;
            $("#progressBar").attr("value", finalVal);
            break;
        }
      }

  });



});

//CSS

  .button-container{text-align: center;}
#progressBar{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: how to achieve this dynamically i can add and remove tab based on that i need to increase/decrease,also using only one button not four buttons @krishna9960